# Splitting a Dataframe at NaN row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is already an answer that deals with a relatively simple dataframe that is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972303/splitting-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values).

However, the dataframe I have at hand has multiple columns and large number of rows. One Dataframe contains three dataframes attached along axis=0. (Bottom end of one is attached to the top of the next.) They are separated by a row of NaN values.

How can I create three dataframes out of this one data by splitting it along the NaN rows?

[image: This is the DataFrame. I intend to split it into three along the NaN rows.]

Answer (score 11):

Like in the answer you linked, you want to create a column which identifies the group number. Then you can apply the same solution.

To do so, you have to make a test for all the values of a row to be `NaN`. I don't know if there is such a test builtin in `pandas`, but `pandas` has a test to check if a Series is full of `NaN`. So what you want to do is to perform that on the transpose of your dataframe, so that your "`Series`" is actually your row:

```
df["group_no"] = df.isnull().all(axis=1).cumsum()
```

At that point you can use the same technique from that answer to split the dataframes.

You might want to do a `.dropna()` at the end, because you will still have the `NaN` rows in your result.

Comment: No need to transpose, just do `df.isnull().all(axis=1).cumsum()`.

Comment: Ah, silly me! I was looking if `isnull` takes an `axis` parameter and didn't check `all` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same question in 2022. Here's what I did to split dataframes on rows with NaNs, caveat is this relies on `pip install python-rle` for run-length encoding:

```py
import rle

def nanchucks(df):
    # It chucks NaNs outta dataframes
    
    # True if whole row is NaN
    df_nans = pd.isnull(df).sum(axis="columns").astype(bool)
    values, counts = rle.encode(df_nans)
    
    df_nans = pd.DataFrame({"values": values, "counts": counts})
    df_nans["cum_counts"] = df_nans["counts"].cumsum()
    df_nans["start_idx"] = df_nans["cum_counts"].shift(1)
    df_nans.loc[0, "start_idx"] = 0
    df_nans["start_idx"] = df_nans["start_idx"].astype(int) # np.nan makes it a float column
    df_nans["end_idx"] = df_nans["cum_counts"] - 1
    
    # Only keep the chunks of data w/o NaNs
    df_nans = df_nans[df_nans["values"] == False]
    
    indices = []
    for idx, row in df_nans.iterrows():
        indices.append((row["start_idx"], row["end_idx"]))
        
    return [df.loc[df.index[i[0]]: df.index[i[1]]] for i in indices]
```

Examples:

```py
sample_df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "b": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "c": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
})

sample_df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "b": [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4],
    "c": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
})

print(nanchucks(sample_df1))
# [     a    b    c
#  0  1.0  1.0  1.0
#  1  2.0  2.0  2.0,
#       a    b    c
#  3  3.0  3.0  3.0
#  4  4.0  4.0  4.0]

print(nanchucks(sample_df2))
# [     a    b    c
# 0  1.0  1.0  1.0
# 1  2.0  2.0  2.0,
#       a    b    c
# 4  4.0  4.0  4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving other answer that support multiple rows with `NaNs`:

```py
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

def split_df_if_row_full_nans(df, reset_header=False):
    # grouping
    df = (df
          .assign(_nan_all_cols=df.isnull().all(axis=1))
          .assign(_group_no=lambda df_: df_._nan_all_cols.cumsum())
          .query('_nan_all_cols == False')  # Drop rows where _nan_all_cols is True
          .drop(columns=['_nan_all_cols'])  # Drop the _nan_all_cols column
          .reset_index(drop=True)
         )

    # splitting
    dfs = {df.iloc[rows[0],0]: (df
                                .iloc[rows]
                                .drop(columns=['_group_no'])
                                )
           for _, rows in df.groupby('_group_no').groups.items()}

    if reset_header:
        # rename column and set index
        for k, v in dfs.items():
            dfs[k] = (v
                    .rename(columns=v.iloc[0])
                    .drop(index=v.index[0])
                    )
            # TODO: this part seems to only works if length of the df is > 1
            # dfs[k].set_index(dfs[k].columns[0], drop=True, inplace=True)

    # # display
    # for df in dfs.values():
    # display(df)

    return dfs

sample_df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "b": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "c": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
})

sample_df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
    "b": [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4],
    "c": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4],
})

for df in split_df_if_row_full_nans(sample_df1).values():
    display(df)
#   1.0 1.0 1.0
# 1 2   2   2
#     3.0   3.0 3.0
# 3 4   4   4

for df in split_df_if_row_full_nans(sample_df2).values():
    display(df)
#     1.0   1.0 1.0
# 1 2   2   2
# 2 NaN 3   NaN
# 3 3   NaN 3
# 4 4   4   4
```

NOTE: This approach use `.isnull().all(axis=1)`, that is only split if all value is `NaN`.