# pandas fillna in column with cumsum of previous rows (reset after every nan)

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum, fillna

I have found a solution that addresses this by rows, but is there a quick way to do it by column?

Here is a quick sample of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['GB',43.76],
['TEN',17.3],
['ARI',0.2],
['ATL',12.3],
['HOU',21.1],
['ARI',1.7],
['ATL',12.6],
['SF',15.0],
['GB',5.7],
[1.0,np.nan],
['GB',43.76],
['TEN',17.3],
['ARI',0.2],
['ATL',12.3],
['HOU',21.1],
['ARI',1.7],
['ATL',12.6],
['BUF',7.0],
['GB',5.7],
[2.0,np.nan]], columns = ['team','points'])
```

I've been trying to manipulate `df['sum'] = df['points'].cumsum()`. Obviously it does the cumlutive sum, but what I need it to do is to restart when/if gets to a `nan` instead of just skipping it over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with helper Series created by check missing value by another `cumsum`:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(df['points'].isna().cumsum())['points'].cumsum()
print (df)
   team  points     sum
0    GB   43.76   43.76
1   TEN   17.30   61.06
2   ARI    0.20   61.26
3   ATL   12.30   73.56
4   HOU   21.10   94.66
5   ARI    1.70   96.36
6   ATL   12.60  108.96
7    SF   15.00  123.96
8    GB    5.70  129.66
9     1     NaN     NaN
10   GB   43.76   43.76
11  TEN   17.30   61.06
12  ARI    0.20   61.26
13  ATL   12.30   73.56
14  HOU   21.10   94.66
15  ARI    1.70   96.36
16  ATL   12.60  108.96
17  BUF    7.00  115.96
18   GB    5.70  121.66
19    2     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way without using `groupby` and assuming that **all the points are positives**, you can do it with `cumsum` on points and `ffill` the nan with the previous value, then remove [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html#pandas.DataFrame.cummax) of the value where points `isna` like:

```
df['s'] = df['points'].cumsum().ffill()
df['s'] -= (df['s']*df['points'].isna()).cummax()
print (df)
   team  points       s
0    GB   43.76   43.76
1   TEN   17.30   61.06
2   ARI    0.20   61.26
3   ATL   12.30   73.56
4   HOU   21.10   94.66
5   ARI    1.70   96.36
6   ATL   12.60  108.96
7    SF   15.00  123.96
8    GB    5.70  129.66
9     1     NaN    0.00
10   GB   43.76   43.76
11  TEN   17.30   61.06
12  ARI    0.20   61.26
13  ATL   12.30   73.56
14  HOU   21.10   94.66
15  ARI    1.70   96.36
16  ATL   12.60  108.96
17  BUF    7.00  115.96
18   GB    5.70  121.66
19    2     NaN    0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same solution as jezrael's, but I'd suggest creating a column representing summation groups, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972303/splitting-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values), where you are checking for np.nan instead of 0. Then doing cumulative sums on those summation groups.